# How to download the contents of a paginated Jquery/JS table?

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, download, pagination

My wish is to download the entire contents of a paginated Jquery or Javascript table, without having to click by hand on every of the 200 pages and copy the contents.

**Example** of table to get :
http://theforexchampionship.com/ranking/

In a more general way, this question applies to tables created by JQuery plugin such as Jquery Datatables ?

Is there a way, like, an automated script, a tool to inject parameters in the JS (such as "0, 999999" boundaries to a JS lib that would provide a function with a min and max bounds), or some way around it??

**Precision** : I am talking about a website of which you do NOT have access to source code

Comment: Are you talking about Data-Scraping? You want to scrape the data from a website you don't own?

Comment: The backend is sending a table, no json, so don't know if that will be usefull for you..

Comment: @Fresheyeball : yes, i didn't know there was a word for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually a data service behind such tables (i.e. something that will reply with the data for every page).

Have a look at the source code of the page to find out how it works and then write your own code which connects to the same source, fetches the data and displays it any way you like.

Note that you don't need a web server for this; a local HTML file with some JavaScript in the same folder will work.

Some things that might hurt on the way:

- If the site needs authorization, you will have to replicate that somehow
- Data in databases is protected by copyright or special legislation in some countries; be aware that someone might object
- Even if it would be legal, some admins/companies hate it when people hammer at their doors. If you don't want to be banned, ask for permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to execute client events and then loop through each table cell using [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)